# как вытянуть категории вместе с минимальным value для каждой категории (название как у категории) с другой таблицы ?LaraveL

Tags: php, laravel

```
    должно выйти  из ниже указанного примера типа:
    $categories = Category::all();
    
    @foreach($categories as $category)
       <p>{!!$category->name!!} = {!!$category_->countsTractor!!}</p>
    @endforeach

Результат:
tractor1 = 25;
tractor2 = 5;
tractor3 = 9;

есть таблица к примеру autoparks

   

    id company tractor1 tractor2 tractor3
    1 moshoz  25        5           15
    2 spbhoz  35        20           41
    3 kirovhoz  60        30           9

есть таблица категории categories

    id name
    1  tractor1
    2  tractor2
    3  tractor3
```

спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
сделал так так же к базе не подключается еще раз? 

это же поиск именно в коллекции?

$categories = Category::all();
$autoparks = Autopark::all();

 @foreach($categories as $category)
       <p>{!!$category->name!!} = {!!$autoparks->min($category->name!!}</p>
    @endforeach
```